# Spectrum of operators $T=I-K$ where $K$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

The Fredholm alterative says that for $T=I-K$, where $K$ is compact, $T$ is is injective iff $T$ is surjective.

So does the following relation between spectrum $\sigma(T)$ and point spectrum $\sigma_p(T)$ hold?
$$\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C},\ \lambda\neq1:\lambda\in\sigma(T)\iff\lambda\in\sigma_p(T)$$
I know this holds for compact operators $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C},\ \lambda\neq0$. Can I really generalize it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can generalise it that way. The correspondence between the spectra is not specific to compact operators, if $S$ is any continuous operator and $T = I - S$, then for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ we have

$$\lambda I - T = (\lambda - 1)I + S = -\bigl((1-\lambda)I - S\bigr),$$

so $\lambda \in \sigma(T) \iff 1-\lambda \in \sigma(S)$, $\lambda \in \sigma_P(T) \iff 1-\lambda \in \sigma_P(S)$ and so on, since $-A$ is injective or surjective, has dense image with a bounded inverse etc. if and only if $A$ has that property.